# LaTeX scrlttr2 change seperation symbol in the from

Tags: latex

In the default letters that I see and use, the address of the from address is as following:

```
Max Mustermann, Beispielweg 23 a, 12345 Köln
```

I would like to change the separation symbol (in the above example ",") to "|".

So it will look like:

```
Max Mustermann | Beispielweg 23 a | 12345 Köln
```

I based my question on the text in [example](https://github.com/janmattfeld/latex-briefvorlage/releases/download/0.0.1/Brief.pdf)

Comment: You need to use `\setkomavar{fromseparator}{|}`

Comment: I get: Class scrlttr2 Error: KOMA-Script variable not defined. \setkomavar{fromseparator}{|}

Comment: `scrlttr2` class does not define the `fromseparator` variable by default

Comment: @Sachin I got a bit confused from your answer...

Comment: I found the solution i was searching for: \setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{~|~}

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{~|~}
```

solved my problem